# Error:(28, 13) Failed to resolve: com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, okhttp

I have a problem with android studio.

I have added the .jar file of okhttp from this link : **https://github.com/square/okhttp** to my libs directory on my android studio. and when I try to add this line :    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'      in the dependencies in build.gradle(Module:app), after trying to syncing it I get error 28, 13. Actually after researching I found out that I can't compile anything in dependencies and sync it remember that I have checked my "android SDK build tool" is installed.

hear is the whole of my code in build.gradle(app) directory:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kasra.stormy"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'], )
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/okhttp-3.2.0.jar')
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
}
```

I'll be very glad and thankful if someone help me fix this problem.

Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either your internet is bad and you can't download that file from JCenter, or you are just missing a `repositories` section in your gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

Also, if you are going to be compiling using gradle instead of a JAR file, then delete the file `libs/okhttp-3.2.0.jar` and remove the line that says `compile files('libs/okhttp-3.2.0.jar')`.

It is also worth mentioning that you don't need any lines that start with `compile files('libs/` because `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'], )` already includes *all* JAR files within the `libs/` folder.

Answer (score 9):

It may help someone. In my case after update `com.squareup.okhttp3` to the latest version, I got this error in Android **Java libaray**. Then I update the Java version to 1.8 which solved my problem.

```
targetCompatibility = '1.8'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
```

Comment: You saved a few hours from my life!

Answer (score 5):

you should change the build.gradle(app):
use

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
```

instead of

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
```

or just follow the guide as mentioned [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp).

Comment: Yours worked for me. I also added this code `repositories { jcenter() }` in the app.gradle file.

Answer (score 2):

Just Replace the dependencies with folowng dependencies and they will work for sure.(100%).
if in future this issue comes again then go to https://square.github.io/okhttp/ and update your dependencies with latest one

```
    //define any required ok http without version
   implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp")
   implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor")

   //define a BOM and its version
   implementation(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.9.0"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `compile files('libs/okhttp-3.2.0.jar')`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by editing my build.gradle as below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),         
    'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
    //compile('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:+') {
    //    exclude group: 'org.json'
    //}
    //replaced as below:
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
}
```

Comment: This answer could use some explanation as to why it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Check your code in app.gradle

`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

`repositories {`
    `jcenter()}`

OR

make your compile okhttp to offline mode, next you uncheck offline mode in setting -> gradle. and try it again

Answer (score -1):

You will not need this

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
```

rather you will need

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
```

As of today the 30th of September 2020
Check https://square.github.io/okhttp/ for documentation